# wso2 api manager SSL Exception

Tags: ssl, api, core

I just set up WSO2 2.6 in windows 10 and publish simple .net core web api without any error tracing on server log,but when i invoke api with OAuth authentication from WSO2 Store, its return SSL Exception below

```
ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: So, what is the question? The message `certificate_unknown` should tell you to look at your certificate-tree.

Comment: I just set up WSO2 2.6 in windows 10 and publish simple .net core web api without any error tracing on server log,but when i invoke api with OAuth authentication from WSO2 Store, its return SSL Exception below

Answer (score 0):

Based on your second reply, this error is an SSL failure when the API gateway tries to communicate with the back end. It seems to me that you are using a HTTPS back end for the particular API. If so, then the public certificate of your back end needs to be included in the client-truststore.jks (/repository/resources/security) in WSO2 API Manager.

You can use the following command to get the public cert of the endpoint or can be exported from the browser as well.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null
```

Use the following command to import the certificate to the keystore

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"
```

Comment: Thank you for the information,But my backend is just http://localhost:8088/api/..